# Need a expertise advise here regarding explicit wait in protractor for non angular apps

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, protractor

I noticed that it is hard to automate nonangular apps with a protractor. I am currently using these methods which I added it to current serenity click and enter functions to add the explicit wait. However, I would like to know if there is a thing I can add to the config file that will automatically wait for the dom to load before it starts to click any button or enter any text value? What is the good practice?

```
import { Enter, Click } from "serenity-js/lib/screenplay-protractor";
import { protractor, element } from "protractor";

var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;

export class Wait{
    constructor() {
    }

    enterValue(text:any, locator:any) {
        //Enter.theValue comes from serenity
        return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(locator)), 5000)

        .then(function(){
            return Enter.theValue(text).into(locator);
        });

    }

    clickOn(locator: any): any {
        //Click.on comes from serenity
        return browser.wait(EC.elementToBeClickable(element(locator)), 5000)

        .then(function(){
            return Click.on(locator);
        });
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add in the config:

```
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
```

Also you can read the difference between them: http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/implicit-explicit-n-fluent-wait/